# How to see questions' / answers' revisions history?

Tags: discussion, revision-history

I apologize in advance, because I know the answer to this question will be very trival. But I've *never* found a way to see questions' / answers' revisions history other than to manually edit the link in the address bar within the "edit" page. Does the drop-down menu in it actually do something? Because it never did *anything* for me, so I really can't tell if that's an issue of my browser or if that's how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a question has been edited, you can view its revision history by clicking on the link above the user card of the most recent editor.

[image: screenshot showing link to revision history]

Comment: Well, now I feel very dumb. Thanks!